# Getting Firebase Parents based on Child Values

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Say that my firebase data structure looks like this picture below:

[image]

I am trying to query the clients based on the `customerNumber` within `settings`.

My most recent attempt, I've tried the following:

```
var number = register.number;

var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/clients/');

ref.orderByChild("settings").orderByChild("customerNumber").equalTo(number).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

but apparently you can't use two `orderByChild()` functions.

So how would I do this? I've built this project way too much to change my structure now so that is NOT an option or a solution that is possible at this point.

I want to return the entire parents based on the `customerNumber` matching within the settings of the parent data structure.

Comment: Try `ref.orderByChild("settings/customerNumber").equalTo(number).on(...`. See this blog post where we introduced the feature: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I get this error when I do that: Error: Query.orderByChild failed: First argument was an invalid key: "settings/customerNumber". Do I need to update my firebase version?

Comment: I updated my version of firebase. I now have this: `ref.orderByChild("settings/customerNumber").equalTo(number).on("value", function(snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot.val());
            });` This console logs null every time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Any thoughts?

Comment: /clients/settings is not a valid path. You need to have /clients/client_id/settings/customerNumber as the path with client_id being one of the uid's from above.  (-Kxxxyyy).  Please copy and paste your code and structure instead of a picture. It saves us a lot of time in trying to answer.

Comment: Answer with working code below. For your next question: include the JSON as text, so I don't have to retype it. Better yet: include a link to a jsfiddle/jsbin with your problem reproduced, so I can just go in there and see your problem (and possibly make it work).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the comment I left doesn't work for you. Here is the snippet I just used to reproduce it:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://mine.firebaseio.com');
ref.child('clients')
   .orderByChild('settings/customerNumber')
   .equalTo('1234567890')
   .once('value', function(snapshot) { 
     console.log(snapshot.val()); 
   });
```

See this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/towewegapa/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You should 'Prefer Flattened Data' as Firebase ask us to do in their documentation : [structuring data in firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)

You could maintain a second index that map the custumerNumber with the Firebasekey in clients

Comment: Read second to last line of question.

Comment: Sorry i didn't saw this : 'So how would I do this? I've built this project way too much to change my structure now so that is NOT an option or a solution that is possible at this point.' It's my bad

Comment: @ilyass: In general it is best to flatten data, but I don't think that applies too much here. The nested settings are addressable as a named key, which is less problematic than when you have a list of lists (of lists of list of...).